# Is it possible to have screenshots of allure report between steps like extent report?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, allure, selenium-extent-report

I'm using **allure** report to generate a report for my tests. earlier I used to use **extent** report. as you know, in extent report you can add logs and screenshot in order of creating them but in allure reports, all the screenshots are going to be shown at the end of steps.

**My Question:** Is it possible to show the screenshots between steps? I want to create a screenshot after each step and I want to see them in the right place and **not** at the end of the report.[image]
[image]
Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call method with taking screenshot in the step:

```
@Test(description = "Screenshot in Step")
public void screenshotInStepTest() {
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    step1();
    step2();
    step3();
}

@Step("Step 1")
public void step1(){
    System.out.println("step 1");
}
@Step("Step 2 with screenshot")
public void step2(){
    System.out.println("step 2");
    screenshot();
}
@Step("Step 3")
public void step3(){
    System.out.println("step 3");
}

@Attachment(value = "Screenshot", type = "image/png")
public byte[] screenshot() {
    return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
}
```

Update:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
//...
@Step("Step 1")
public void step1(){
    //...

    Allure.addAttachment("Any text", new ByteArrayInputStream(((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES)));
}
```

Report:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. but still if I have some steps in one method, the screenshots will appear at the end. right? I attached another image to the question.

Comment: All `@Step` s  with `screenshot()` method inside will have a screenshot. Add `screenshot()` method to the `Check if the Log in was successful` and you'll get screenshot as you need.

Comment: But it's not possible to have it for `Allure.step("something")` inside of a method. right?

Comment: You can use `Allure.addAttachment()`, check the answer update

Comment: I tested also this method. changing the attached file name can be helpful to find it easier. but still it appears at the end and not where it has to.

Comment: What Allure version do you use. I tested with 2.12.1

Comment: I'm using **Gradle** so my dependency is `compile group: 'io.qameta.allure', name: 'allure-gradle', version: '2.8.1'`

Comment: Try with 2.12.1 version

Comment: I'm using Maven  and allure version is :  <allure.version>2.13.2</allure.version>. Still not work.

Comment: @Sers, please tell me where to put it

Comment: For @Step annotation to work, you need aspectJ library available. In case you for some reason cannot use it, then you can  Allure.getLifecycle().startStep(...) and Allure.getLifecycle().stopStep(...) around screenshot generation. You also wight have to use Allure.addAttachment(...) to make screenshot available for allure.