# Attach web-page screenshot to all "then" allure steps (pytest-bdd, selenium, allure)

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, allure, pytest-bdd

I'm writing pytest-bdd + selenium + allure tests. And i need to attach screenshot to each verification step - @then("..."). Pytest bdd have "after step" hook which i implemented like this:

```
def pytest_bdd_after_step(request, feature, scenario, step, step_func, step_func_args):
if step.keyword == 'Then':
    driver = request.getfixturevalue('driver')
    allure.attach(driver.get_screenshot_as_png(), name='screenshot',
        attachment_type=allure.attachment_type.PNG)
```

It works fine, but the screenshot appeared AFTER all steps in the report and not inside the step:

[image: Allure report: screenshots appeared after all steps]

So my question is: is it possible to attach something to the step itself in "before/after" hooks? 
Thanks.

Comment: I'm afraid this is not possible. I also was trying to do something similar in Java but Allure documentation is poor about this topic. Each attachment regardless type is always added at the end of test body.

Comment: I had the same problem. I think this will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58728908/is-it-possible-to-have-screenshots-of-allure-report-between-steps-like-extent-re

Comment: @M3trix, Greg Burghardt, yes, this approach will work. And actually i think this is only solution, unfortunately.